# My neural network only returns +1 in binary classification

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement NN for binary classification. output Layer has only 1 node, if the result of it is greater than 0.5, then it belongs to +1, else -1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris


def fit_NeuralNetwork(X_train, y_train, alpha, hidden_layer_sizes, epochs):
    layer_units = ([len(X_train[-1])] + hidden_layer_sizes + [1])
    W = [np.random.rand(n_fan_in_ + 1, n_fan_out_) for n_fan_in_, n_fan_out_ in
         zip(layer_units[:-1], layer_units[1:])]
    # W = np.true_divide(W, 10)
    X_train = np.insert(X_train, 0, 1, axis=1)
    error_list = []
    error_dic = {}
    for _ in range(epochs):
        error_over_epoch = 0
        np.random.shuffle(X_train)
        for N, x_n in enumerate(X_train):
            X_n, S_n = forwardPropagation(x_n, W)
            g_n = backPropagation(X_n, y_train[N], S_n, W)
            W = updateWeights(W, g_n, alpha)
            # error_over_epoch += errorPerSample(X_n, y_train[N])
            error_over_epoch += 1 if pred(x_n, W) != y_train[N] else 0
        error_list.append(error_over_epoch / len(X_train))
        error_dic[error_over_epoch] = W
    print(error_list)
    return error_list, W


def forwardPropagation(x, weights):
    Xl = np.array(x)
    W = np.array(weights)
    S = []
    X = [x]
    for index, l in enumerate(W):
        wl = np.array(l)
        sl = np.transpose(wl).dot(Xl)
        Xl_before_activation = sl
        if index != len(W) - 1:
            activation_function = np.vectorize(activation)
            Xl = activation_function(Xl_before_activation)
            Xl = np.insert(Xl, 0, 1, axis=0)
        else:
            output_function = np.vectorize(outputf)
            Xl = output_function(Xl_before_activation)
        X.append(Xl)
        S.append(sl)
    np.delete
    return np.array(X), np.array(S)


from copy import deepcopy


def backPropagation(X, y_n, s, weights):
    weights_copy = deepcopy(weights)
    g = [None] * len(X)
    X = np.array(X)
    for layer, Xl in enumerate(reversed(X)):
        layer = len(X) - layer - 1
        if layer == len(X) - 1:
            delta = 2 * (Xl[0] - y_n) * derivativeOutput(s[-1][0])
            g[layer] = np.array([delta])
        elif layer > 0:
            derivatives = np.zeros([len(Xl) - 1, len(Xl) - 1])
            for i in range(len(Xl) - 1):
                derivatives[i][i] = derivativeActivation(Xl[i + 1])

            Wl = weights_copy[layer]
            # Wl = weights[layer]
            Wl_t = np.array(Wl)
            g[layer] = np.dot(np.dot(Wl_t, (g[layer + 1]).T)[1:].T, derivatives)
            # g[layer] = ((Wl_t).dot((g[layer + 1]).T)[1:]).T.dot(derivatives)

    g = g[1:]

    updatedW = weights_copy
    # updatedW = weights
    for layer, Xl in enumerate(X[:-1]):
        updatedW[layer] = np.dot(np.array([Xl]).T, np.array([g[layer]]))

    return (updatedW)


def updateWeights(weights, g, alpha):
    return np.subtract(np.array(weights), np.multiply(np.array(g), alpha))


def activation(s):
    return 0 if s <= 0 else s
    # return np.tanh(s)


def derivativeActivation(s):
    return 0 if s <= 0 else 1
    # return (1 - np.tanh(s) ** 2)


def outputf(s):
    return (1) / ((1) + np.exp(-s))


def derivativeOutput(s):
    # return (outputf(s)) * (1 - outputf(s))
    return (np.exp(-s)) / ((1 + np.exp(-s)) ** 2)


def errorf(x_L, y):
    if y == 1:
        return np.log(x_L)
    else:
        return -np.log(1 - x_L)


def errorPerSample(X, yn):
    return errorf(X[-1][-1], yn)


def derivativeError(x_L, y):
    if y == 1:
        # derivative of np.log(x_L)
        return 1 / (x_L)
    else:
        # derivative of -np.log(1 - x_L)
        return 1 / (1 - x_L)


def pred(x_n, weights):
    # print('x of n',x_n[-1])
    # if x_n[-1] != 1:
    #     x_n = np.insert(x_n, 0, 1, axis=0)
    x, s = forwardPropagation(x_n, weights)
    res = 1 if x[-1][-1] >= 0.5 else -1
    return res


def confMatrix(X_train, y_train, w):
    # Add implementation here

    X_train = np.insert(X_train, 0, 1, axis=1)

    y_pred = []
    for x_n in X_train:
        y_pred.append(pred(x_n, w))

    # the confusion maxtrix that we will return
    # matrix = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    matrix = np.zeros((2, 2), np.int8)

    # Populating our matrix using the prediction data
    for index, y in enumerate(y_train):
        if y == -1 and y_pred[index] == -1:
            matrix[0][0] += 1
        elif y == -1 and y_pred[index] == 1:
            matrix[0][1] += 1
        elif y == 1 and y_pred[index] == -1:
            matrix[1][0] += 1
        else:
            matrix[1][1] += 1

    # returning the result
    return matrix
    # return confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred)


def plotErr(e, epochs):
    x_axis = range(1, epochs + 1)
    plt.plot(e)
    plt.show()


def test_SciKit(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test):
    nn = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(300, 100), random_state=1, alpha=10 ** (-5))
    nn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    pred = nn.predict(X_test)
    cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, pred)
    return cm


def test():
    X_train, y_train = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train[50:], y_train[50:], test_size=0.2)

    for i in range(80):
        if y_train[i] == 1:
            y_train[i] = -1
        else:
            y_train[i] = 1
    for j in range(20):
        if y_test[j] == 1:
            y_test[j] = -1
        else:
            y_test[j] = 1

    err, w = fit_NeuralNetwork(X_train, y_train, 1e-2, [30, 10], 100)

    # plotErr(err, 100)

    cM = confMatrix(X_test, y_test, w)

    # sciKit = test_SciKit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

    print("Confusion Matrix is from Part 1a is:\n", cM)
    # print("Confusion Matrix from Part 1b is:\n", sciKit)


test()
```

At this point I really don't know where might cause this logical error, my best guess is `backPropagation`

Comment: Why do you want to write your NN from scratch, when you have already implemented NN, like MLPClassifier for instance? Use it, it is already done and tested, it works. You may find others in tensorflow and keras.

Comment: On the other hand, just a hint: did you balance your data first ?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu Thank you for your reply. It is an assignment, and because of the Coronavirus its grade is very vital, the whole university is shutdown and my final grade depends on this assignment. I have no control over the input data, the only thing I can do is changing the methods I developed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an assignement, it is better to do this by yourself. But I can give you some hints that will help you.

Here are some ideas for your debugging :

1. What do you mean by having no control of the input data? At least, you can print it, it's shape (`df.shape`), etc.
2. If you have a classification, your data must be balanced,  that means having the same amount of samples for each class.
3. And finally, make prints at each level of your code in order to see if your program outputs what you want.

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem) is some more information concerning gradient vanishing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured out that my code logically is correct. But I'm facing vanishing gradient problem.

Comment: In the instructions we are asked to classify the data into two groups, {-1, +1} so it is not in my hands.

Comment: OK, so you fond the problem in your code. I updated the answer with a link towards info on grandient vanishing. It seems your assignement is precisely about that.